# Get content from div with HTML Agility pack with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, parsing

I am using the parser HTML Agility Pack in a project. I am using the PubNub chat script. I want my C # program to take the chat messages and print them on a label through the div id = "box".

Here's PubNub's HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
        <meta name="description" content="Example of a JavaScript chat app using PubNub JavaScript V4 SDK.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript,PubNub,Chat,chat-room,chatting,SDK,PubSub-sdk,tutorial">
        <meta name="author" content="Chandler Mayo">
        <title>JavaScript Chat | PubNub</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="https://www.pubnub.com/?devrel_pbpn=javascript-chat"><img src="https://d2c805weuec6z7.cloudfront.net/Powered_By_PubNub.png" alt="Powered By PubNub" width="150"></a><p>
        <p>Enter chat and press enter.</p>
        <input id="input" placeholder="Your Message Here"/>
        <p>Chat Output:<p>
        <div id="box"></div>

        <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.23.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>(function(){
            var pubnub = new PubNub({publishKey : 'demo',subscribeKey : 'demo'}); // Your PubNub keys here. Get them from https://dashboard.pubnub.com.
            var box = document.getElementById("box"), input = document.getElementById("input"), channel = 'chat';
            pubnub.subscribe({channels: [channel]}); // Subscribe to a channel.
            pubnub.addListener({message: function(m) {
                box.innerHTML = (''+m.message).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' + box.innerHTML; // Add message to page.
            }});
            input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
                (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && pubnub.publish({ // Publish new message when enter is pressed. 
                    channel : channel, message : input.value, x : (input.value='')
                });
            });
        })();</script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My C# code to get the data form div id "box" :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    const string url = "https://javascript-chat.com/";
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(url);
    string msg = doc.GetElementbyId("box").InnerHtml;
    label7.Text = msg.ToString();

}
```

But even when there are messages in the chat, the label does not print the data. Can someone help me?

Comment: It may be easier to get the message from the History API - [`https://ps.pndsn.com/v2/history/sub-key/demo/channel/chat?count=100`](https://ps.pndsn.com/v2/history/sub-key/demo/channel/chat?count=100)

Comment: I'll try. Thank you, Sir.